# phpMyAdmin - error in processing request 404

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, webserver

I have a issue on my webserver. It is a XAMPP with Apache and MySQL.

Everytime when I click on the "User" tab of phpMyAdmin I get this (phpmyadmin) error:

**Error in processing request**

**Errorcode: 404**

**Errortext: Not found**

This also happens, when I click on any table to look up the data.

What does this mean? What can I do? Can anybody help me? :)

I've tried to make a export of my data. So I clicked on "Export" and then selected "SQL".

When I click on "OK" I get a usual HTTP-404 Error ("object not found").

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Answer (score 0):

When you are changed config port as 8080 php.ini.
You can open http://localhost:8080/PHPMyAdmin/.

For example **http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/**

Comment: please format your answer, for more info can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)